# How to auto increment from last number in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I design a signUp page in node js with mongodb and i want anytime a user signUp the user should get a unique number like 0001 and the next signup to get 0002 and so on.

Here is what i have try doing.

I have tried copy some php method maybe i can implement it, but it didnt work out

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  // Check Validation 
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      errors.email = 'Email already exists';
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    } else {

      // create Unitno
   const no = User.find(max(unitNo)).then(
      if (user.unitNo > 0){
        const str = "" + 1
        const pad = "0000"
        const answer = pad.substring(0, pad.length - str.length) + str;
        return answer
      }else{
        console.log("error")
      }

    )



      const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        secretToken,
        unitNo: no,
        });
});
     bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;

            warehouse
              .save()
            newUser 
             .save()
              .then(user => res.json(user))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

here is my mongo db schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  unitNo:{
    type: Number,
  },

  role:{
    type: Number,
    default : 4,
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Here is how i expect the the user collection to look like

```
{
  "isVerified": false,
  "_id": "5d6cf8de973dae75df75b19c",
  "email": "yourmail@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2a$10$2c3dRWx4Q643u0PpJnRad.377eBOVhiWOdYUyQB1lPmVCRJ.afFMS",
   "role": 4,
   "unitNo": 0001, /** this should keep increasing when new user signup on the platform*/
  "date": "2019-09-02T11:11:26.591Z",
  "__v": 0
}

{
  "isVerified": false,
  "_id": "5d6cf8de973dae75df75b19c",
  "email": "yourmail2@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2a$10$2c3dRWx4Q643u0PpJnRad.377eBOVhiWOdYUyQB1lPmVCRJ.afFMS",
   "role": 4,
   "unitNo": 0002, /** this should keep increasing when new user signup on the platform*/
  "date": "2019-09-02T11:11:26.591Z",
  "__v": 0
}

{
  "isVerified": false,
  "_id": "5d6cf8de973dae75df75b19c",
  "email": "yourmail@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2a$10$2c3dRWx4Q643u0PpJnRad.377eBOVhiWOdYUyQB1lPmVCRJ.afFMS",
   "role": 4,
   "unitNo": 0003, /** this should keep increasing when new user signup on the platform*/
  "date": "2019-09-02T11:11:26.591Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a unique number using mongoDB?

Comment: i am not using a unique number, i only need a all new signing up to have a warehouse number

Comment: Ok, which version of node are you using?

Comment: Hi Mason and welcome to the Stack Overflow. First of all, I think you should avoid using this kind of method (increment the number in your code) since it leads you to a race condition. You can use `$inc` function from MongoDb.

Comment: node -v 10.16.0

Comment: i am new to node js and mongodb @ksugiarto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

`User.find().sort({unitNo : -1}).limit(1);`

for the find the max `uniqueNo` from the collection, instead of

`User.find(max(uniqueNo))`,

like:

```
employeeController.save = function(req, res) {
        Employee.find().sort({unitNo : -1}).limit(1).then((data) => {
            if(data){
                console.log(data[0].unitNo);
                updatedunitNo = data[0].unitNo+1;
                var employee = new Employee({
                    name : req.body.name,
                    email : req.body.email,
                    phone : req.body.phone,
                    unitNo : updatedunitNo
                });
                employee.save(function(err, employee) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.render("../views/employees/create");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Successfully created an employee.");
                        console.log("new employee : "+employee);
                        res.json({ employee: employee });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

};

and got the answer in console :

> `port is listen on : 5020
>   connection succesful
>   inside save
>   3
>   Successfully created an employee.
>   new employee : { _id: 5d78f1e0e85b680b948a9b87,
>     name: 'asedfw',
>     email: 'sdfsdf@gmail.com',
>     phone: 8877787777,
>     unitNo: 4,
>     __v: 0 }`

Comment: you are storing the query in some variable so the error can be of it because we cant store any mongo query inside the variable.

Comment: i got this error
`{ ValidationError: users validation failed: unitNo: Cast to String failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" at path "unitNo"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/user/Desktop/logistics/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:59:24)`

Comment: yes, you are adding the string value at the place of number because your `unitNo` is in the number format . now you can add the `unitNo` in the number format not in the string like ; const unitNo = unique.unitNo + 1, then every time it will increses.

Comment: My types remain unchanged am still using the Number type and did you run the code from your end.

Comment: yes, you can change the code where API have been call as per i updated the code and it is working for me successfully i already gives you the console answer. hope you will get :)

Comment: your most welcome :) , if, you find any other query or error can ask me any time.

Comment: can you please use my code structure to work it out, still keeps bringing ```Cast to String failed for value "Promise { <pending> }" at path "unitNo"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"Promise { <pending> }"',
        kind: 'String',
        value: [Promise],
        path: 'unitNo',
        reason: [MongooseError] } },
  _message: 'users validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }``` this even when i change ```unitNo``` to both String and Number

Comment: `unitNo` is the format of number and you storing it in the string format then it will not work. you have to do as i have done for this field because in the promise we can add in the same format.and also you have to pass it in the one call ass i have pass inside the API call you can't do outside it.

Comment: But you never tell me how or where to ask you if i have any other problem

Comment: you can ask here. this is the platform where we can ask the questions and get the answers.  so you can ask here with your query, whatever you written the code, whatever errors you will get etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957802/how-to-get-the-values-from-my-mongodb-database-as-a-value/57957915?noredirect=1#comment102348827_57957915

Comment: i can't understand what you want to do exactly,  you want to store `dimension` as the global const like you will use it anywhere in your app right ? or you want to store in every db ?

Comment: my email validation refuses to work either i use findOne or Find

Comment: For this type of validation its better to use find only so it can find all the records related to it.