# How to get the values from my MongoDB query a const

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a MongoDB Schema call settings, this schema has some values that I want each of the value to be used in another schema as a constant

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const SettingSchema = new Schema({
  dimension:{ 
    type: Number
  }
paystack:{
    type: String
  }
paypal:{
    type: String
  }
stripe:{
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = Settings = mongoose.model('settings', SettingSchema);
```

```
{
  "_id": "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb",
  "dimension": 166,
  "paystack": "A1212asdvsdvdd12121313",
  "paypal": "Bfwfw2ewrewrr32ASDdd133",
  "stripe": "Fr1aEacstewrr32ASDdd133",
  "__v": 0
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create a const dimension that will pull out that 166 from my settings schema.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. If you want to get out data from mongodb you take the mongoose function https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find.

Comment: what i meant is that i want to be able to get just a single value. get the value of dimension and put it in a const, the same goes for every thing

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is how can i create a ```const dimension``` that will pull out that ```166`` from my settings schema

Answer (score 0):

**Schema**

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    // Create Schema
    const SettingSchema = Schema({
      dimension:{ 
        type: Number
      },
    paystack:{
        type: String
      },
    paypal:{
        type: String
      },
    stripe:{
        type: String
      }
    });

    module.exports  = mongoose.model('settings', SettingSchema);
```

In the file you want data .

```
    const settingModel = require('../models/setting.model');
        router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
           let userId = "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb";
           const result = await settingModel.findOne({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb");
           console.log(result[0].dimension); 
           res.json(result);
      });
```

Comment: i can do this, what i meant is that i want to be able to a single value, like i want to be able to get the value of the dimension alone and not print everything and made it a constant

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is how can i create a ```const dimension``` that will pull out that ```166`` from my settings schema

Comment: You can latter use it like `const dimension = found.dimension ` if found is object .. If found is array of object , type the following code  .,`const dimension = found[0].dimension ` @mason

Comment: kindly update it in your code, help me put it together

Comment: I have updaated the answer , you can check it . @Mason

Comment: That is where the problem i want it to be a global const that can be used anywhere in my app

Comment: So you can simply declare the `const dimension ` in the global and assign the value insde  the query function . @Mason

Comment: here is what i tried
 ```const dimension = Settings.find({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb"}).select('dimension').exec((err , found) =>{
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }else{
     return found[0].dimension;
   }
});
```
but it shows ```undefine``` when i console log(dimension), but it if i console log within the else statement it works fine

Comment: Then what is the value of `dimension `? . Did you checked it ? @Mason

Comment: this one was able to work within the function, but if you check it outside the function, it bring dimesion is not define

```Settings.find({_id : "5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb"}).select('dimension').exec((err , found) =>{
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }else{
     const dimension = found[0].dimension;
     console.log(dimension)
   }
});```

Comment: Getting back wiith solution . @Mason

Comment: it can only work with that route i want it to be const on it on, though i know it will only work with async function thank you anyway, i promise to come edit ur code and also make it correct as soon i got it solved because you alrea.dy made it easy.

Comment: If you want to make it use in everywhere in the file then it is better to use `var` *or* `let` keyword instead of `const` . Because at the time you declare the `const` variable , at that time only you need to assign it's value . Therefore we must use the `const` inside the async function . So its better to declare variable with `let` or `var ` because if you declare that variable at global , use can edit there value later and also can use it everywhere in the file . @Mason   . Hope you understand the point . If you have any query , feel free to ask asnytime .

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
const settingModel = require('../models/setting.model');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
settingModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { '_id': ObjectId(5d7f77d620cf10054ded50bb) }
        },
]).exec((err , data) =>{
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }else{
     console.log(data);  
     console.log(data[0].dimension);
   }
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is how can i create a ```const dimension``` that will pull out that ```166`` from my settings schema

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the `dimension` value, first you have to make a call to your database to obtain the object you want to extract the data from.

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const Setting = mongoose.model('settings');

module.exports.dimension = (req, res, next) => {
    Setting.findOne({ _id: req._id },
        (err, setting) => {
            if (!setting)
                return res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: 'Setting not found' });
            else
                return res.status(200).json({ status: true, setting: _.pick(setting, ['dimension']) });
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I want to make this a constant that can be used in  my application

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is how can i create a ```const dimension``` that will pull out that ```166`` from my settings schema